# gcm server get HTTP Status 500 - Could not send message after 6 attempts

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've had success registering my device on gcm_demo page, message like this "1 device(s) registered!".

But when I click send message on page, it finally turn out like this:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not send message after 6 attempts
type Exception report
message Could not send message after 6 attempts
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

exception

```
java.io.IOException: Could not send message after 6 attempts
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:136)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:83)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: Please, improve your question by adding code and fixing the grammar.

Comment: Provide steps to reproduce the error. I.e. your configuration and a code snippet.