# GCM - Could not post JSON requests to GCM after 6 attempts

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, google-cloud-messaging

I am having the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956356/gcm-server-get-http-status-500-could-not-send-message-after-6-attempts). I will try and provide more information.

I am using Play Framework, writing in Java. I wrote a plugin called PushNotificationQueue. PushNotificationQueue runs both an iOS and an Android Push Message Queue. Below, for reference, is my GCM implementation.

```java
public class AndroidPushNotificationQueue {

  // (constructors and fields not included for brevity)
  // constructor starts a daemon thread

/**
* Sends a notification. 
* @param notifyKeys - device tokens
* @param data - data to send
**/
public void sendNotification(List<String> notifyKeys, Map<String, String> data) {       
    if (notifyKeys.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Builder b = new Message.Builder();
    if (data != null) {
        for (String key : data.keySet()) {
            b.addData(key, data.get(key));
        }
    }
    if (testMode) {
        b.dryRun(true);
    }
    Message message = b.build();
    queue.add(new Notification(notifyKeys, message));
}

public void stop() {
    stopped = true;
    sendingThread.interrupt();
}

private class SendNotificationRunner implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                sendNotifications();
                //TODO: handle errors
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if (stopped)    break;
                Logger.error("Error processing android notification", e);
            } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
                if (stopped)    break;
                Logger.error("Error processing android notification", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (stopped)    break;
                Logger.error("Error processing android notification", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (stopped)    break;
                Logger.error("Unexpected Exception in Android Notification thread", e);
            }
        }
        Logger.info("Stopping Android push queue");
    }

    private void sendNotifications() throws IOException, InterruptedException, InvalidRequestException {

        Notification n = queue.take(); // will wait until an element becomes available
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(n.message, n.notifyKeys, NUM_RETRIES);
        List<Result> results = result.getResults();

        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
            Result r = results.get(i);
            String mId = r.getMessageId();
            String notifyKey = n.notifyKeys.get(i);

            if (mId == null) {
                String error = r.getErrorCodeName();
                if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
                    removeDeadRegistration(notifyKey);
                } else {
                    //TODO: something better when error occurs
                    Logger.error("Error sending android notification to " + notifyKey + ": " + error);
                }
            } else {
                String newNotifyKey = r.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
                if (newNotifyKey != null && !newNotifyKey.equals(notifyKey)) {
                       // do something to handle this error case - not included for brevity
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This works ... sometimes. Most of the time I get the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Could not post JSON requests to GCM after 6 attempts
  at com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:319) ~[classes/:na]
  at utils.AndroidPushNotificationQueue$SendNotificationRunner.sendNotifications(AndroidPushNotificationQueue.java:131) ~[classes/:na]
  at utils.AndroidPushNotificationQueue$SendNotificationRunner.run(AndroidPushNotificationQueue.java:103) ~[classes/:na]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_55]
  [debug] application - Endpoint - BaseStationAuth.getUsername
```

I did some digging and found this in the GCM implementation.

```java
/**
   * Sends a message to one device, retrying in case of unavailability.
   *
   * <p>
   * <strong>Note: </strong> this method uses exponential back-off to retry in
   * case of service unavailability and hence could block the calling thread
   * for many seconds.
   *
   * @param message message to be sent, including the device's registration id.
   * @param registrationId device where the message will be sent.
   * @param retries number of retries in case of service unavailability errors.
   *
   * @return result of the request (see its javadoc for more details).
   *
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if registrationId is {@literal null}.
   * @throws InvalidRequestException if GCM didn't returned a 200 or 5xx status.
   * @throws IOException if message could not be sent.
   */
  public Result send(Message message, String registrationId, int retries)
      throws IOException {
    int attempt = 0;
    Result result = null;
    int backoff = BACKOFF_INITIAL_DELAY;
    boolean tryAgain;
    do {
      attempt++;
      if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINE)) {
        logger.fine("Attempt #" + attempt + " to send message " +
            message + " to regIds " + registrationId);
      }
      result = sendNoRetry(message, registrationId);
      tryAgain = result == null && attempt <= retries;
      if (tryAgain) {
        int sleepTime = backoff / 2 + random.nextInt(backoff);
        sleep(sleepTime);
        if (2 * backoff < MAX_BACKOFF_DELAY) {
          backoff *= 2;
        }
      }
    } while (tryAgain);
    if (result == null) {
      throw new IOException("Could not send message after " + attempt +
          " attempts");
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I have varied the number of attempts - 5, 10, 15.

- Has anyone else run into this problem? I have found a few people online with the same problem, but as of yet no solutions can be found.
- Any suggestions on things I could try to fix it?
- Should I simply keep increasing the number of attempts?

Comment: How many recipients are you dealing with, and how big is your Message size?

Comment: I also get this problem. Please share if you can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem. but fix it.

1.
I think just edit Interval time varible that 'Sender.BACKOFF_INITIAL_DELAY = 1000;" to 'Sender.BACKOFF_INITIAL_DELAY = 10000;' in Sender.java on com.google.android.gcm.server.

you can read Sender.java file. it's open source.

2.
  I changed collaps_key value  as long type in gcm payload.
  I think google server not accept the special char for collaps_key. ".", ",", any alpabet.

Good luck.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for looking into it! Once I confirm it works i'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing all the IP addresses accepted (allows from any IP) in the GCM server config fixed this for me. Since a secret key is already used, limiting the IP addresses is (for most) an unnecessary precaution.

Answer (score 0):

My application thrown also the exception with the message "GCM - Could not post JSON requests to GCM after 6 attempts". So I set a breakpoint at the post(...) method call (line 190 of Sender.java) in the sendNoRetry(...) method call and stepped around in order to get some useful info regarding the response.

In my case I got a 401 http status code because I used a wrong api key.

Comment: @ZachSaucier - you're way too quick on the draw, he was not posting a new question, but rather how he found the solution to solving the problem in his own code.  ie, he's suggesting that the OP do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One possible other cause for this message: The Google Cloud Messaging is deprecated as of May 29, 2019

Details:

I stumbled upon this question when I received the same error message

> Could not post JSON requests to GCM after 6 attempts

After debugging I found out that the library I am using: https://github.com/google/gcm
kind of masks the real error which was:

> 400 – Bad Request  Error=DeprecatedEndpoint

(I guess you could also raise the debug level to see the real error message instead of debugging it.)

So, it turns out the endpoint is old and should be migrated to firebase messaging endpoint.